# JavaScript. How to Compare Input Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I'm stuck with this problem for 3 days now... Someone please help me.

> **Challenge 5**
>   Construct a function `intersection` that compares input arrays and returns a new array with elements found in all of the inputs.

```
function intersection(arrayOfArrays) {

}

console.log(intersection([[5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]]));

// should log: [5, 15]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array by filtering with just checking if the other array contains the value.

This works for arrays with unique values.

> [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):
>
> > If no `initialValue` is provided, then `accumulator` will be equal to the first value in the array, and `currentValue` will be equal to the second.
>
> The callback
>
> ```
> a.filter(v => b.includes(v))
> ```
>
> filters array `a`. If the array `b` includes the value of `a`, then this value `v` is included in the `accumulator` for the next iteration or as final result.
>
> ```
>      accumulator            currentValue           new accumulator
>           a                       b                    result
> --------------------    --------------------    --------------------
> [     5, 10, 15, 20]    [15, 88,  1,  5,  7]    [             5, 15]
> [             5, 15]    [ 1, 10, 15,  5, 20]    [             5, 15]
> ```

```js
function intersection(arrayOfArrays) {
    return arrayOfArrays.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(v => b.includes(v)));
}

console.log(intersection([[5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]]));
```

Comment: Hi Nina,
I'm a beginner and trying to figure out how your code works. Is it possible to explain more details about how reduce((a, b) => a.filter()) work?

Answer (score 4):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the arrays to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of counts, with the value as key. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the Map to [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries). Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the Map's entries to remove all entries, which value is not equal to the `arrayOfArrays` lenth. Extract the original number from the entries using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function intersection(arrayOfArrays) {
  return [...arrayOfArrays.reduce((r, s) => {
    s.forEach((n) => r.set(n, (r.get(n) || 0) + 1));
    
    return r;
  }, new Map())]
  .filter(([k, v]) => v === arrayOfArrays.length)
  .map(([k]) => k);
}

console.log(intersection([[5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]]));
```

Comment: Something tells me that will only confuse OP more.

Comment: yeah it took me awhile to learn =>, reduce, and spread&rest operator lol

Answer (score 0):

**First try to find out the intersection of two arrays which is the `base problem`. Then try to build up for variable number of arrays passed as arguments for intersection. You can use `reduce()` for doing that.**

```js
function intersectionOfTwoArrays(arr1, arr2)
{
   return arr1.filter(x => arr2.some(y => y === x)); 
}


function intersection(...arrayOfArrays)
{
 return arrayOfArrays
        .reduce((a, b) => intersectionOfTwoArrays(a, b));
}

intersection(
[5, 10, 15, 20], 
[15, 88, 1, 5, 7], 
[1, 10, 15, 5, 20]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the first array in the array of arrays and check which of its value is present in all the other arrays.

Here is an example:

```js
function intersection(input) {
    let firstArray = input[0];
    let restOfArrays = input.splice(1);
    return firstArray.filter(v => restOfArrays.every(arr => arr.includes(v)));    
}

const input = [[5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]];
const result = intersection(input);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the common elements. Let me show you how:

```
var Array1 = [5, 10, 15, 20]
var Array2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7]
var Array3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]
var found = []
var Final = []
var c = 1;e = 1;
for (i = 1;i<=Array1.length;i++){
    for (k = 1;k<=Array2.length;i++){
        if (Array1[i] == Array2[k]){
            Found[c] = Array[i];
            c++;
        }
    }
}
for (n = 1;n <= Found.length ; n++){
    for (m = 1;m <= Array3.length ; n++){
        if (Found[n] == Array3[m]){
            Final[e] = Found[n]
            e++; 
        }
    }
}
//the Array Final Contains 5 , 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with even if there is duplicate in same array.. like in my example added 5 twice in arrayEle[1];

```
var arrayEle = [[5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 5], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]]
var startIndex = 1;
var newArray = [];
for (var x = 0; x < arrayEle[0].length; x++) {
  var temVal = 1;
  var value;
  for (var y = 1; y < arrayEle.length; y++) {
    for (var z = 0; z < arrayEle[y].length; z++) {
      if (arrayEle[y][z] == arrayEle[0][x]) {
        temVal++;
        value = arrayEle[y][z];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (temVal == arrayEle.length) {
    newArray.push(value);
    console.log(value);
  }
}
console.log(newArray);


//log: [5, 15]
```